# Not able to Track and search stolen android phone

Tags: lost-phone

Recently my Smartphone (Lenovo Vibe X3) stolen by someone. It’s very painful for me.
When it was stolen, I was able to ring my phone till 10-15 min but that time I was not able to sign in my gmail account on desktop computer so that I can track it using Android Device Manager. My phone was locked with fingerprint and patterns both. And some apps were locked with App Locker..

After 2-3hrs, I was able to sign in my gmail on the same desktop computer and with the same password but Android Device Manager couldn’t locate device. I don’t know how that stealer manipulated everything. Even an anti-theft application was also installed. However, it couldn’t be traced.

I request to all expert users for assisting me for two concerns.
Is it possible to trace device with IMEI? Please let me know, how to do this? How to tackle such problems? And
Please let know some best apps that can trace a device even with IMEI and mobile GPS.

I complaint to nearest police station but it doesn't seem helpful. That's why I need assistance from expert user. If stealer removes my gmail account from phone but GPS is ON, in that case will ADM work?

I have gone through a [link](https://play.google.com/store/apps/developer?id=Family%20Safety%20Production). Is it helpful for an android device, if these are installed before device lost/theft?

Apart from this please provide me better tips & tricks.

Regards
GNS

Comment: Have you already consulted our fine [lost-phone tag-wiki](https://android.stackexchange.com/tags/lost-phone/info)? You're not the first one asking this. Being rather a frequent issue, we've compiled some first-aid and links you should try. We don't want to repeat the same things over and again :)

Answer (score 0):

If your GPS on phone is off you will not locate it via ADM. 
Yes, phone can be located with IMEI but you can't do that, police can. So go to police and report stolen device and bring box of the phone for the IMEI and proof that is your device, but keep in mind that police doesn't really bother with stolen phones.